# Slope calculation misunderstanding for linear function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my Math book I'm solving a case where this is the situation:

"The demand curve for good X is linear. At a price (p) of 300 the demand is 600 units. At a price of 680 the demand is 220 units. Also the supply curve for good X is linear. If the price is 400 then the supply equals 200 units, whereas for a price of 800 the supply will be 1000 units."

I'm asked to formulate the system of equations.

For the demand function I did:

`SLOPEqd = delta y / delta x = -1` (`delta y 680-300, delta x 220-600`)

Which I could use and verify by the coordinates and I got the formula `Demand(x) = -x + 900`)

If I do the same for the supply function I end up wrong:

`SLOPEqs = delta y / delta x = 0.5` (`delta y 800-400, delta x 1000-200`)

If I try to verify this for the first supply point (800, 1000) I would get:

`Supply(x) = 0,5x + 600` but this is incorrect for the second point (400, 200). In the answers I found the slope for the supply function should be `2` instead of `0,5`. Why is this? I think I'm overlooking something super obvious, but please enlighten me.

(sorry, I haven't figured out how to write the equations as fancy as I see them in other questions)

Comment: My recommendation is that always in this kinds of graph questions, to take some paper and sketch the graph :) Then you would have immediately seen what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates the wrong way round. Supply is your $y$ co-ordinate (dependent variable) and Price is you $x$ co-ordinate (independent variable) so you should have

$\Delta y = 1000 - 200 = 800$

$\Delta x = 800 - 400 = 400$

$\text{Slope } = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{800}{400} = 2$

$\text{Supply } = 2 \times \text{Price } - 600$

You had your $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates the wrong way round in your Demand calculation as well, but since the slope there is $-1$ whichever way  round you have the co-ordinates, this did not matter.

Answer (score 1):

For supply you have computed the following:

> `SLOPEqs = delta y / delta x = 0.5` (`delta y 800-400, delta x 1000-200`)
>
> If I try to verify this for the first supply point (800, 1000) I would get:
>
> `Supply(x) = 0,5x + 600`

Presumably, this is because you think the point $(x,y) = (800,1000)$ should lie on the graph of this function.

Now look carefully. In one place you have $\Delta y = 800 - 400,$
in another you have $x = 800.$ But the $800$ comes from the exact same given quantity (a price on the supply curve) in both places. So is it a value of $x$ or a value of $y$?

If you decide prices should be $x$ in both places, then you'll have
$\Delta x = 800 - 400 = 400,$
$\Delta y = 1000 - 200 = 800,$ and slope $\Delta y/ \Delta x = 2.$
Then when you try $(x,y) = (800,1000)$ you'll get
$$ S(x) = y = 2x - 600. $$

On the other hand, if you say price should be $y$ in both places, you'll still have the slope $0.5,$ but now you're trying to fit a function to the point
$(x,y) = (1000,800),$ from which you get
$$ y = 0.5x + 300 = 0.5 S(y) + 300. $$

As noted in another answer, the conventions of economics are confusing in the regard that they tend to plot the supply and demand *curves* with quantity on the horizontal axis and price on the vertical axis,
yet the supply and demand *functions* give quantity as a function of price.
My recommendation to minimize the confusion about this is:

Never use $x$ or $y$ to denote a price or quantity (of supply or demand).
Always use $P$ for price and $Q$ for quantity (possibly with subscripts) when you are naming variables.

Comment: I completely forgot to thank you for your help. Thanks! +1

Comment: Oh, good, I'm glad to know it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is because of the strange (to me) way these things are defined.

According to the [Demand curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_curve) and [Supply curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply_(economics)) Wikipedia pages, these are conventionally *plotted* with price $P$ on the *vertical* (i.e. $y$) axis, and quantity $Q$ on the *horizontal* (i.e. $x$) axis, which is exactly what you have used to calculate your slopes.

However the *demand function* and the *supply function* are conventionally written in the form $Q=$ function of $P$, so the plots are actually plots of the *inverse demand function* and the *inverse supply function*. If that is what is being asked for, your slopes need to be converted into their inverses.

Comment: I completely forgot to thank you for your help. Thanks! +1